# How to make hex file for attiny402 microcontroller using winavr

Tags: microcontroller, avr, attiny

I have written a code in the 'Programmer's Notepad' of winavr. But when I went to make the hex file, I didn't find the attiny402 microcontroller in 'mfile'.

[image]

Can anyone help me? Now, what should I do? it is very urgent for me.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winavr has not been updated since 2010; the ATtiny402 was released in 2018. According to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATtiny_microcontroller_comparison_chart the ATtiny402 requires gcc arch id avrxmega3. So winavr will not be able to work. Check whether you have a new enough version of gcc to support ATtiny402 (avrxmega3), the version installed with winavr is probably out of date.